Fix google account / OAuth 401 deleted_client / Reset google cloud
I am not using Google Cloud. I'm just using google account.
I need to login to some site with Google account, there are according option.
Sometime ago I registered successfully with Google account there.
Now I'm unable to login - when I press the button I've been redirected to the page, where it says
[Enter Google Account]
Access denied:         The OAuth client was deleted.
authentication error   If you are the developer of this app, read info about error.
                       Error 401: deleted_client
<and my email here>

Digging the web some suggests to enter Google Cloud, IAM & Admin, delete project, search for storages, clear them etc then recreate project, fill some paths, tokens etc.
But... the problem is I don't know any paths, I have no scripts there to enter tokens etc, I just want to enter to someone others site, just as a regular user.
After what told to do, I have more problems that before I entered first time Google Cloud...
As a "regular user" I don't need to know or do anything in Google Cloud - at blank google account this type of (OAuth) login to that site works ok, but not the account where I touched Google Cloud.
At new test google accounts when I go to console.cloud.google.com I see a message where Cloud says I can create new project. There are NO any projects, it's clear, blank etc.
When I created project at my main email after some of that suggestions (made by google team too) then deleting (put to the deletion queue) project I suppose there are something broken  and I don't understand what broken and how to fix it.
My first tries to fix that was some time ago. Now I repeat to create new project, entered OAuth consent screen and found again (remembered) that it will not help, because "Edit app registration" (External) asks me for "app name" (I don't know the app name asking OAuth because I'm not an owner of that external site, "application home page" - because the same. So it's impossible to fix this 401 deleted_client with such steps.
I can't move to new google account. This account is my main for nn years. There are some third party apps that works well, I tested some of them with logout-login by Google.
But some sites didn't work and led me to 401 deleted_client and have no ideas how to fix that. There are no "reset Google Cloud" or similar or I can't find it. New users has clear Google Cloud without any projects.
Browser cache is not an issue - tested account(s) at clean browser. Tested accounts without any Google Cloud projects (blank new accounts) - OAuth works, login to site works ok. Accounts where Google Cloud project was created by "suggestions" then deleted - OAuth didn' works, impossible to login to site, 401 deleted_client.
Anyone knows how to fix that? Thank you.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with GCP, instead it is related to some website which uses the sign in with Google option. Correct us if we are wrong and also can you provide the details of the application which you are trying to login to and the flow of how the login takes place if you are the application developer.

I'm not the owner of the site where I try to log in, I mention it in my Original Post. For example, site "techtobo" (I'll not write full url of it to avoid deletion of comment, site can be easily found in searchengines). The problem is more deeper because to contact admins of that site (if it's their problem and not mine) - I can't write to them if I didn't log in.

The error indicates that the google cloud project or the oauth client in that project has been deleted.
Only the owner of the application can fix the issue by either restoring the deleted project if applicable, or creating a new OAuth client for the application and re-deploy it.
Since you mention you are not the owner of the site, you should instead report the issue to the site's support.

Updated my OP with a comment.
